# Bootstrap Tab Selection in different page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have three different tab in three different page. how do i keep different tab selected after page refresh. If i keep second tab selected in One page, in other pages second tab also gets selected. Below is my code for tab

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hash in your links to activate any tab from the url by javascript.

URL: http://someurl.com/#tab-id

```
$(function(){
  if(window.location.hash!=''){
    var hash=window.location.hash;
    $('.nav-tabs a[href='+hash+']').click();
  }
}
```